# Textmate Rails3 no such file to load — bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, textmate, bundler

When I try to run tests from TextMate in Rails3 i get an error that I trace back to boot.rb. When I try to run boot.rb via textmate I get this error:

```
LoadError: no such file to load — bundler

method gem_original_require in custom_require.rb at line 31
method require  in custom_require.rb at line 31
at top level    in boot.rb at line 4
```

This is even in a brand new rails project. I am able to run the same boot.rb file from terminal calling

```
ruby <path_to>/boot.rb
```

I can verify that my TM_RUBY variable is the same as when i call `which ruby` from the command line. Do you have any clue why I might be getting this error?

Comment: (Commenting to add that we've established that yes, the bundler gem is installed.)

Comment: might be the GEM_PATH environment variable not being set..?

Comment: Sounds like something is misconfigured in your tests and without sufficient backtrace, I don't think I can help further. Also, try updating the bundles in Textmate as they might be at fault. Incidently, mine don't work either! :-/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I ran into this same problem with TextMate and RVM. What you need to do:

1. Create a wrapper script for the gemset you want to use, using this RVM command:

   ```
   rvm wrapper ree@rails3 textmate
   ```

   This will add a new alias to your RVM install called `textmate_ruby`. As you can probably tell this assumes you're using Ruby Enterprise (ree) and a gemset called rails3, but any RVM string will work here.
2. Open TextMate's preferences window, go to Advanced > Shell Variables. You need to create (or update) the `TM_RUBY` shell variable to the following:

   ```
   /path/to/your/.rvm/bin/textmate_ruby
   ```

   If your RVM is installed in your user dir (like mine), that'll be:

   ```
   /Users/[YOUR USER NAME HERE]/.rvm/bin/textmate_ruby
   ```
3. (Optional) You may also need/want to set the `RUBYOPT` shell variable, to instruct Ruby to load rubygems. This may be necessary to make certain bundles (like RSpec) work. Just set the value to `rubygems`.

This should be all you need.

Answer (score 3):

I found it was simplest to use the `rvm-auto-ruby` approach.

Locate the `rvm-auto-ruby` binary using `which`:

```
$ which rvm-auto-ruby
```

The result is the path to the auto-loading binary:

```
/Users/yourusername/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby
```

Add this path to TextMate under: *Preferences -> Advanced -> Shell Variables*

It functions like an alias that points to your active version of Ruby.

Screenshot: http://cl.ly/23Yl

These instructions are available on the RVM website: https://rvm.io/integration/textmate/

Comment: Are you using Rails 4.2 and Ruby 2.2? Does it work? I can't make it working, when I execute a textmate bundle, and loads boot.rb: crash when executes `require 'bundler/setup'`

Answer (score 1):

To get TextMate to use the same RVM Ruby interpreter as the command line, I did the following:

- On the command line, typed `which ruby` - for me, this was `/Users/mgp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby`
- In TextMate preferences, i added `/Users/mgp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin` to the front of my `PATH` shell variable.
- In TextMate preferences, i added a new shell variable `GEM_PATH` with the value `/Users/mgp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180:/Users/mgp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global`

Answer (score 0):

This could be happening of you're using RVM (ruby version manager) and textmate doesn't know about it.

Does rake test work from the command line?

Comment: rake test does work from the command line and i am using RVM.